# Cypress - I don't know which selector to choose for a list with more options

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress, devextreme

I have a dropdown list and several names are displayed. I don't know how to call cypress to select one of the options from the dropdown menu

```js
<div class="dx-item dx-list-item" role="option" aria-selected="false">
  <div class="dx-template-wrapper dx-item-content dx-list-item-content">
    <span style="color: grey;">charlie sheen</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The class `dx-item` looks like a good candidate.

```js
cy.contains('.dx-item[role="option"]', 'charlie sheen').click()
```

Make sure you have opened the dropdown. You haven't mentioned it, so presume you have already done that.